# Using Twilio to send pre-filled message from iOS handset instead of asking user to enter code?

Tags: ios, twilio

I've seen several applications that use Twilio for SMS verification go from:

Sending the user a 4-5 digit code to enter on their handset

to

Pre-filling a 32+ character SMS message that the user sends from their device to the services Twilio number.

Is there any documentation out there on how to implement an approach like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

It sounds like your asking two different questions, one regarding two factor authentication and one regarding autocreating an SMS message on the device for the user to sent to Twilio.

If I've got that correct, then I'd start be working through the [Two-Factor Authentication How To](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/two-factor-authentication?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) article that walks through setting up SMS-bsased two factor authentication.

Another resource to check out is the [Add Two-Factor Authentication to your Website with Google Authenticator and Twilio SMS](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/04/add-two-factor-authentication-to-your-website-with-google-authenticator-and-twilio-sms.html?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) blog post.

As far as generating a text message on a device, I think that is going to greatly depend on what kind of mobile device you are targeting.

Hope that helps.